# Gap within inline-block elements with different high

Tags: html, css, display

I have container with css elements. All of the elements has display: inline-block property. The problem is that one of the element is twice hire than the rest and instead of having two elements on the side I have only one and a lot of white space. This is how it looks:

[image]

my css is:

```
.productBlock {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: darkgray;
    height: 271px;
    width: 161px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.productBlock-higher {
    background-color: darksalmon;
    height: 548px;
    width: 161px;
    margin: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I remove the white space and add element another element there?
I would like to add move two elements on the right side of the higher div. It should look like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you need to set the vertical align top
https://codepen.io/opmasan/pen/vYNvbpZ

```
.productBlock {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but not exactly. I want to nest one more element where the white space is.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I added:

```
.productBlock-higher {
    float: left;
}
```